# html-based code editors

Tags: javascript, html, css, syntax-highlighting

Is codepress [ http://code.google.com/p/jquery-codepress-plugin/ ] still the best option for color-coded, line-numbered, tab-catching syntax editing?  Seems like the team developing it has lapsed.

edit: I'm looking for something I can fork/improve upon/integrate/push back to the community.

Answer (score 3):

Bespin is pretty impressive: https://bespin.mozilla.com/

PHPAnywhere looks interesting too: http://phpanywhere.net/

Comment: Yea, i like what they're doing a lot - unfortunately i'm looking for something i can fork/improve upon/integrate/push back to the community.  BeSpin seems pretty tailored for their application.

Comment: @tdonia - You should have provided that information in your question :)

Answer (score 2):

A couple of options are

[CodePress](http://sourceforge.net/projects/codepress/)
[Bespin](https://bespin.mozilla.com/)
[EditArea](http://www.cdolivet.com/index.php?page=editArea)

I've used all 3 and find Bespin the nicest looking, but hardest to customize. EditArea is solid and whilst not easy to customise is much easier than bespin.

Answer (score 1):

Check Codemirror. We are using that in our project [kodingen.com](http://kodingen.com) together with Bespin and Ymacs.